# How to impute missing values with mean by group and replace existing values

Tags: r

I have a longitudinal dataset with data for the height of a person at the first visit. The other rows are empty. 
But sometimes a person has two values and two different values.
I would like to replace missing values with the average of the group and replace the existing value also with the mean. I tried:

```
data$variable <- ave(data$variable, data$group, 
                     FUN = function(x) ifelse(is.na(x), mean(x, na.rm = TRUE), x))
```

This code replaces the missing values by the mean height but still leave the existing height.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that missing values are replaced by the group and that for IDs with repeats in a group, those particular IDs would need to have an average of the two of them.

Therefore, you would need to do two functions:

```
data$variable <- ave(data$variable, data$group, 
                     FUN = function(x) ifelse(is.na(x), mean(x, na.rm = TRUE), x))

data$variable <- ave(data$variable, data$group, data$ID,
                     FUN = mean)
```

In `dplyr` syntax, you would do:

```
library(dplyr)

data <- data%>%
  group_by(group)%>%
  mutate(variable = coalesce(variable, mean(variable, na.rm = TRUE)))%>%
  group_by(ID, add = T)%>%
  mutate(variable = mean(variable))%>%
  ungroup()
```

And `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(data)
data[, variable := ifelse(is.na(variable), mean(variable, na.rm = T), variable), by = group]
data[, variable := mean(variable), by = .(ID, group)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of replacing missing values with mean for each group (species) in this case. Admittedly not the most elegant solution.

```
library(tidyverse)

# creating an example data with NA inserted randomly for 20 values of Petal.Length
set.seed(4)
row_with_na <- sample(1:nrow(iris), 20)
iris[row_with_na, "Petal.Length"] <- NA

# generate the mean of Petal.Length by the Species     
ref <- iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% summarise(mean_petal_length = mean(Petal.Length, na.rm=TRUE))

# replace the NA based on Species

iris %>% mutate(Petal.Length = ifelse(is.na(Petal.Length) & Species == "setosa", ref[ref$Species == "setosa", "mean_petal_length"],
                                      ifelse(is.na(Petal.Length) & Species == "versicolor", ref[ref$Species == "versicolor", "mean_petal_length"],
                                             ifelse(is.na(Petal.Length) & Species == "virginica", ref[ref$Species == "virginica", "mean_petal_length"], Petal.Length))))
```

Comment: Unfortunately I have 1532 different IDs.

Comment: Haha~! That's why I said it's not an elegant solution. @Cole's solution is great for the purpose though. Do test it out.